# Exclude a path in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have been writing an spring cloud gateway service to act as a proxy for other microservices.
the application.yml file is something like this:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          // some registeration
        provider:
          // some providers

  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: forward-route2
          uri: https://my-domain.net
          predicates:
            - Path= /gateway/**
          filters:
            - TokenRelay
            - RewritePath=/gateway/(?<remaining>.*), /${remaining}
```

here I will every request of form `/gateway/**` to something like `'https://my-domain.net/**'` and everything works fine.

Now I want to exclude some paths. In other words I want my gateway to have a controller with prefix `'/gateway/manage/'` for some purposes. for example I want to ***exclude*** all Uris like `'/gateway/manage/**'` from being redirected to `'https://my-domain.net'`.

How should I achieve this goal ?

P.s: I'm using springboot3.

Thanks is advance.

EDIT: also how can I exclude all these Uris `'/gateway/manage/'` from Spring security? Is there any way to do that in application.yml ?

Comment: Have you tried adding the controller?

Comment: yes. and It will be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

I found what to do.
add something like this to your application.yml file :

```
  route:
    - id: exclusion
      uri: no://op
      predicates:
        - Path= /gateway/manage/**
    - //other routes.
```

if you are using spring security, do not forget to modify your configs if necessary.